# How to position a TikZ picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I have a problem with positioning a TikZ picture. I want to position a half circle, but I don't know how I should do it.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw [domain=0:180] plot ({cos(\x)}, {sin(\x)});

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Just position it generally in space-time? Or is there some particular place you'd like to position it in?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not the easiest way to draw a circle (or half circle).
But if you want to position your `plot` you can use `shift`.

Here is an example, and some more commands (all that I know) that can draw circles in TikZ.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7]{standalone}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[ultra thick, domain=0:180,shift={(.5cm,1.5cm)}] plot ({cos(\x)}, {sin(\x)});

    \draw (-3,0) circle(1);
    \draw[brown] (-2,0) ellipse(1);
    \draw[green] (-2,0) arc(-180:180:1);
    \draw[blue] plot[smooth cycle,tension=1] coordinates{(-1,0)(0,1)(1,0)(0,-1)};
    \draw[red, xshift=1cm] \foreach \r in {0,...,3}{[rotate=90*\r]
    (-1,0) .. controls (-1,0.555) and (-.555,1) .. (0,1)};
    \node[yellow,draw,circle,minimum height=2 cm] at (2,0){};
    \draw[cyan,bend left=45] (2,0) to (3,1) to (4,0) to (3,-1) to (2,0);
    \path[gray] (3,0) edge[out=90,in=180] (4,1)
                (4,1) edge[out=0,in=90] (5,0)
              (5,0 )edge[out=-90,in=0] (4,-1)
              (4,-1) edge[out=180,in=-90] (3,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```